# How to get row index or column index on right click in datagrid

Tags: flex3

I want to add/delete row from datagrid when a user right click within the data grid but actually i am unable to get the row index(or column index or selectedIndex) .Any one ??

Comment: you can add a right click handler on each column, and let that take the responsibility of removing itself...

Comment: also just for brevity, right click handlers will not work when you are using flex to create a webapp

Comment: This can be accomplished, but you will see the Flash context menu. I will post the source if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this DataGrid =>

`itemRollOver="updateMenu(event.rowIndex)"
private function updateMenu(index:Number):void
{
   trace("row index"+index)
}`